# Find a subset of dataframe based on partial string matching from another column of values in R

Tags: r

I have a column of values with unique identifiers that look like this:

```
df$1 <– c("identifier:ab134:4sfh", "identifier:gh164:9sgh", "identifier:3h1v4:kk9gh"
```

Some of them are in another column in a separate data frame with 71 columns but in that data frame, they are often clustered like this:

```
df2$1 <– c(""identifier:ab134:4sfh|identifier:gh164:9sgh", "identifier:sfghskg8:kk9gh|identifier:fj893n:9sgh|identifier:gh164:9sgh",...)
```

I need to find all rows which have any of the identifiers in them in the second dataframe. I would strsplit the column but I want to keep the rest of the second dataset as it is.

I have tried using this code both ways (i.e. df1 %in% df2 and df2 %in% df1) but obviously it's not giving me all the matches because it's trying to match whole strings rather than substrings:

```
new_subset <- subset(df$1, trimws(1) %in% trimws(df2$1))
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I’m really not sure what I can add. I need a match for every row and I’ve used the code above (which doesn’t work).

Comment: If you can provide expected output for the vectors you showed, it would help `lapply(v1, function(x)  unlist(lapply(strsplit(v2, "|", fixed = TRUE), 
        function(y) match(x, y))))` Also try `grep(df2$1, df$1)`

Comment: So I tried this and I got a very long list that looks like this: List of 8806
 $ : int [1:14037] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : int [1:14037] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : int [1:14037] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : int [1:14037] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

Comment: I want an output that looks like this: df$2 <– c("identifier:ab134:4sfh", "identifier:gh164:9sgh") but only includes matches from df$1

Comment: You've got mismatched quotation marks in your code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `grep` to find matching strings.

```
new_subset <- df[grep(paste0("^(",paste(df2$z, collapse = "|"),")$"), df$z),]
new_subset
#[1] identifier:ab134:4sfh identifier:gh164:9sgh
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(z=c("identifier:ab134:4sfh", "identifier:gh164:9sgh", "identifier:3h1v4:kk9gh"))
df2 <- data.frame(z=c("identifier:ab134:4sfh|identifier:gh164:9sgh", "identifier:sfghskg8:kk9gh|identifier:fj893n:9sgh|identifier:gh164:9sgh"))
```

Comment: I get an error message in response: paste(df2, , collapse = "|") : 
  argument is missing, with no default

Comment: @OliverL I wrote `paste(df2, collapse = "|")` and not `paste(df2, , collapse = "|")`

Comment: @OliverL I have updated the data-set in the question from `vector` to `data.frame`. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. So now it's saying `"Error in grep(paste0("^(", paste(df1, collapse = "|",  : invalid regular expression '^("identifier:ab134:4sfh|identifier:gh164:9sgh"..)`

Comment: Could it be something to do with `collapse = "|"` - do I need to change it somehow to make it comply with regex rules?

Comment: @OliverL I wrote `grep(paste0("^(",paste(df2$z, collapse = "|"` and not `grep(paste0("^(", paste(df1, collapse = "|"`

Comment: Sorry yes I am using a different identifier in my actual code so I had to change it back. I did use ‘df2’ and it’s giving me the same error message.

Comment: @OliverL Then you have ``"` in what is not the case of your example data-set.

Comment: Do you mean I have an extra "? The data looks identical to what I've posted above

Comment: @OliverL Can you create the data as it is posted in your question?

Comment: I've just realised that the error message isn't exactly the same. It's `Error in grep(paste0("^(", paste(df2, collapse = "|", : invalid regular expression '^("identifier:ab134:4sfh TRUE |identifier:gh164:9sgh TRUE..."` So it looks like it's telling me that it's there but there's something going wrong with the pasting right?

Comment: I wrote `df2$z` you wrote `df2`